# UITableView still leaves space on top even after disabling contentInset Xcode 9.4.1

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to place a table view inside of a basic view controller without any padding on the top and nothing I've tried has worked, no matter what I do there is a gap up top. I placed the following code in my viewDidLoad() for the view controller:

```
if #available(iOS 11, *) {
   tableView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .never
} else {
   self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false
}
```

I've gone into storyboard and disabled those settings as well manually:
[image: View Controller]
[image: Table View]

I do have custom cells I'm not sure if that matters, I do add insetting to the cells but even when I remove that code I have that gap.

Here's the code I customized for my cells:

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        contentView.frame = UIEdgeInsetsInsetRect(contentView.frame, UIEdgeInsetsMake(cellSpacingHeight, 0, 0, 0))
    }
```

I've spent a couple hours googling around and I can't figure it out. I'm using the latest swift and Xcode to build this. I even tried to print the values for the tableView's content inset and it came up as all 0s. Does anyone know why I still have the offset or inset up top in my table view?

Answer (score 2):

Wow okay so I finally figured it out, I had set the table view style to Grouped at some point instead of Plain. Once I made it plain, everything worked, I hope this might help someone else in this position!

Comment: You can keep it grouped.. but if you do, override `heightForHeaderInSection` and return `CGFloat.leastFiniteMagnitude`. Do the same for the footer.. Then in `viewForHeaderInSection`.. `return UIView()` (I think this part is optional).. Do the same for footer.. This is because tableView by default has a header height of 44.0